# Does $\langle \Psi, \mathbb{I} \rangle_G=\langle Res_H\Psi, \mathbb{I} \rangle_H$ always hold?

Tags: representation-theory, inner-products

Let $G$ be a group and $H < G$. Let $\Psi$ be a character. Let $\mathbb{I}$ be the trivial representation

Does $\langle \Psi, \mathbb{I} \rangle_G=\langle Res_H\Psi, \mathbb{I} \rangle_H$ always hold? It almost looks like Frobenius-Reprocity Theorem but I cannot see the justification as to why it would hold

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this doesn't always hold. Take $\Psi$ to be any irreducible representation of $G$ which contains the trivial representation when restricted to $H$. Then $\langle\Psi,\Bbb{I}\rangle=0$, but $\langle Res_H\Psi,\Bbb{I}\rangle_H\neq 0$.

Comment: Why does $\langle\Psi,\Bbb{I}\rangle=0$ hold?

Comment: Sorry, should have also said $\Psi$ should be non trivial.  Then this is Schur's lemma.

Comment: And there are plenty such examples; eg consider a group $G$ with normal subgroup $H$. Then an irreducible nontrivial rep of $G/H$ does the job.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by your first comment. I am aware of the result Schur's Lemma

Comment: If $\Psi$ is nontrivial and irreducible, then Schur's lemma says that $\langle\Psi,\Bbb{I}\rangle\neq 0$ if and only if $\Psi=\Bbb{I}$. So if $\Psi$ is a nontrivial irreducible representation which contains $\Bbb{I}$ upon restriction to $H$ you have a counterexample.